# Issue with freeswitch mod_Port audio in raspberry pi 4 (debian buster)

Tags: raspberry-pi, freeswitch, portaudio, debian-buster, audio-device

I have loaded mod_portaudio in freeswich. But after that when pa rescan the device, i found no device in the device list. While the pi is connected to a bluetooth speaker and also a headset with a aux cable and those are working fine in the system.

Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on this and shortly believed to have solved it (see https://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2020-August/133883.html and https://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2020-August/133884.html), but it wasn't true:

1. I was testing with my headset and had successful "pa looptest" indicating both indev & outdev were working
2. Then, when I tested that in the context of my application for auto-answering incoming calls (I called with my mobile phone while putting it in front of a tv so that I can test if I would hear anything on my headset), I didn't notice that in that case the mic was not working because I had the headset on my ears and was hearing the tv (because of success of looptest, I was just assuming that the mic would also be working)
3. But when I finally got a Plantronics Calisto 620-M Bluetooth Speakerphone, even the looptest failed. At this moment, I tested more carefully my headset again, and there I found out that the mic was not working.
4. Because it seemed that something device-specific should be the reason for failure, I also tested with my bluetooth earphones; there the effect was equivalent to Calisto speakerphone.
5. I finally got a USB speakerphone and tried that one, but in that case "pa rescan" failed to find any devices.

With all four devices, always arecord and aplay were working perfectly, and the above issues appeared only with mod_portaudio.

I don't have any idea what the issue could be with the usb, but with the three bluetooth devices, I still believe that something device-specific should be causing the problems here, e.g. the sample rate. But, currently I am lacking time to further work on this...